# Getting DateTime difference in OrientDB

Tags: node.js, orientdb

I have the following Carts table schema of orientDB. All I wanted to do is to select those records where

```
(CurrentTime - timeStamp) >= expiration
```

[image: Table Schema]

I had also tried to achive my goal thorugh converting to unix timestamp and tried following queries

```
SELECT * FROM Carts WHERE eval("('+new Date().getTime()+' timeStamp.asLong())/1000") >= expiration
```

And also by following technique but when :parameter is passed in eval funtion it convert it into '?' and don't return required data.

```
db.query(
        'SELECT eval("'+new Date().getTime()+' - timeStamp.asLong()") as DIFF, :nowTimeStamp as NOW, timeStamp.asLong() as THEN FROM Carts ',
        {
            params: {
                nowTimeStamp: new Date().getTime()
            }
        }).then(callback);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Carts WHERE eval("SYSDATE().asLong() / 1000 - timeStamp.asLong() / 1000") >= expiration
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I like your breaking the LCM technique but unfortunately eval is not dividing values with 1000. I figure it out but following query

SELECT eval("SYSDATE().asLong()/1000 - timeStamp.asLong()/1000") as diff, SYSDATE().asLong() as now, eval("SYSDATE().asLong()/1000") as NOWSEC,timeStamp.asLong() as then, eval("timeStamp.asLong()/1000") as THENSEC  FROM Carts